# android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to android.service.dreams.DreamService$DreamServiceWrapper

Tags: android, screensaver, daydream, dreamservice

I'm struggling with exception

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.hubalek.android.apps.reborn.pro/android.service.dreams.DreamActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to android.service.dreams.DreamService$DreamServiceWrapper
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3968)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

This issue is exclusive to Samsung devices with Android 11. Does anybody any idea how to fix it?
Except disabling this feature for Samsung phones with Android 11.

I'm afraid it is outside of my code.

Source code for `DreamActivity` seems to be quite straightforward - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/service/dreams/DreamActivity.java

Comment: Bro, did you fix it?